# How to perform validation in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, mean

I have a form like below:

```
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="nomargin">Let us know your concern or question and we will try to respond within 24 hours.</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body paddingmodal2">
    <form id="support-form" name="supportForm"  class="nobottommargin" novalidate="">
      <div class="col_full">
            <label for="login-form-username">Description <small>*</small></label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text"  ng-class="{'error': submitted && supportForm.description.$error.required}" id="login-form-username" name="username" class="sm-form-control" ng-model = 'support.description' required/>
        </div>
        <div class="alert" role="alert" ng-class="{'alert-danger':!isLoginSuccess, 'alert-success':isLoginSuccess}" ng-show="isShowLoginAlert" ng-bind="loginSubmitStatusMsg"></div>
        <div class="col_full nobottommargin no-margin-col-full">
            <button type="submit" class="button button-3d button-black nomargin col_full" id="login-form-submit" name="submit-bt" ng-click="saveSupportData(supportForm,support)" ng-disabled="isDisableLoginBtn">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.saveSupportData = function(supportForm,data){
                 if(supportForm.$invalid){
                    return;
                }
}
```

when I click on button the text area border should be highlighted but its not happening.

Can anyone suggest help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A form is an instance of FormController. The form instance can
>   optionally be published into the scope using the name attribute.
>
> Similarly, an input control that has the ngModel directive holds an
>   instance of NgModelController. Such a control instance can be
>   published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute
>   on the input control. The name attribute specifies the name of the
>   property on the form instance.
>
> This implies that the internal state of both the form and the control
>   is available for binding in the view using the standard binding
>   primitives.
>
> This allows us to extend the above example with these features:
>
> Custom error message displayed after the user interacted with a
>   control (i.e. when $touched is set) Custom error message displayed
>   upon submitting the form ($submitted is set), even if the user didn't
>   interact with a control

It should be

```
ng-class="{'error': submitted && supportForm.username.$error.required}"
```

because your field name is username.
Submitted should be true when form is posted
Try this

```
$scope.saveSupportData = function(supportForm,data){
    $scope.submitted=true;
     if(supportForm.$invalid){
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use $invalid also for required fields
ng-class="{'error': submitted && supportForm.description.$invalid}"

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me.

Comment: Glad to help you.